# Автоматизация публикаций с сайта в телеграмм

Tags: вконтакте, telegram-bot, автоматизация

Добрый день, 
подскажите пожалуйста, есть сайт (доступа к коду нету и т.д.) На нем постят таблицы. Например, план работ на месяц. Так вот, как сделать что бы эти таблицы, за 2 часа до начала работ слали месседж в телеграмм нужным людям.
Была идея, вытаскивать таблицу, добавлять автопостингом в группу в вк в нужное время и сразу репост в телеграмм. 
Как это все автоматизировать? Куда копать, что почитать? или может есть другие варианты? Плюс таблицы эти могут обновляться, поэтому нужно что бы скрипт обновлял данные в табилце раз в 30 минут, например.

Comment: С таким расплывчатым вопросом вам можно порекомендовать только учить языки программирования, способы парсинга HTML-документов и Telegram Bot API.

Comment: вопрос скорее всего в алгоритме. Какой он должен быть и что для этого нужно? какие технологии использовать? автоматический парсинг+автопостинг в вк+ репост в телеграмм через ifttt? или может как-то проще можно сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Собственно, задача состоит из трёх частей:

1. Как вытаскивать таблицы;
2. Как отправлять информацию в телеграм;
3. Как выполнять задачу периодически.

Поскольку не указано на каком языке и в какой системе необходимо решать задачу, выберем язык и систему произвольно: пусть это будет Linux и Python.

**Как вытаскивать таблицы**

Читайте про Python HAML scraping. Я рекомендую lxml или BeautifulSoup:
Пример:

```
import urllib2

# откуда скачиваем текст
wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"

#Скачиваем текст, возвращаем результат в page
page = urllib2.urlopen(wiki)

#импортируем функции для парсинга из bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#выполняем парсинг
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

# дальше можно работать с данными находящимися в soup
```

**Как отправлять инфрормацию в telegram**

Существует огромнейшее количество реализаций Bot [API телеграмма](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples), который интересует нас в данном случае (вообще, как справедливо замечает *Anatol*, существует два API: Telegram API и Bot API; в данном случае нас интересует второе).

Воспользуемся, например, telepot:

```
import telepot
bot = telepot.Bot('*** INSERT TOKEN ***')
chait_id = ...
bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "insert your message")
```

**Как выполнять задачу периодически**

Здесь есть несколько вариантов, условно которые можно разделить
на две группы:

1. Использовать для этого внешний сервис (например, cron);
2. Использовать какой-либо внутренний модуль для периодического исполнения задачи.

Во втором случае я рекомендую пакет [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule).
Просто и красиво:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: _Существует огромнейшее количество реализаций клиентов API телеграмма._ - это Вы про **Bot API** или про **Telegram API**?

Comment: @Anatol: Про Bot API; уточнил в тексте; спасибо за справедливое замечание!

Comment: Решить можно с помощью обоих апи, если бы описали оба варианта - было бы супер

Comment: @Anatol: Сделаем